# convert to int using python

Tags: python, int

How can I convert the output **"span.text[pos+2:]"** of the code below to an integer using Python:

I have tried int(span.text[pos+2:]), but does not work

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


url = "https://maps.google.com.au/maps?saddr=A6&daddr=A6&hl=en&ll=-33.877613,151.039867&spn=0.081236,0.083599&sll=-33.869204,151.034546&sspn=0.081244,0.083599&geocode=FYSu-v0d2KMACQ%3BFbp0-_0dJKoACQ&mra=ls&t=m&z=14&layer=t"

content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

div = soup.find('div', {'class':'altroute-rcol altroute-aux'}) #get the div where it's located
span = div.find('span')
pos = span.text.find(': ')
print 'Current Listeners:', span.text[pos+2:]
```

**Update:** It may be helpful to show the contents of a few variables:

```
span.text == u'In current traffic: 8 mins'
span.text[pos+2:] == u'8 mins'
```

Comment: What does it say when it does not work?

Comment: `int(something)` will convert something to an int and raise a ValueError if it fails.

Comment: `span.text[pos+2:]` results in `8 mins` in your case. Do you want to have the `8` in that string as your int?

Comment: It's hard to pinpoint anything without knowing what `content` is.  Please post that.

Comment: So what happened when you tried `int(...)`?  I have to say, "does not work" is not a useful phrase when seeking help with a technical issue of any kind. We can't help unless we know what happened, while "does not work" often doesn't even tell us what *didn't* happen.

Comment: the span text will be something like "current traffic: 7" and I am after the 7 when i apply the pos+2 after the ":"

Comment: @Ossama, there is also something after the number, that's what's causing you trouble.

Comment: @Ossama: I've edited your post to show the possible contents of span.text. If that's wrong, please edit out my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, the following will work. I'm not sure how fragile it is though.

```
int(span.text[pos+2:].split(" ")[0])
```

As follows:

```
In [31]: span.text
Out[31]: u'In current traffic: 8 mins'

In [32]: span.text[pos+2:]
Out[32]: u'8 mins'

In [33]: span.text[pos+2:].split(' ')
Out[33]: [u'8', u'mins']

In [34]: span.text[pos+2:].split(' ')[0]
Out[34]: u'8'

In [35]: int(span.text[pos+2:].split(' ')[0])
Out[35]: 8
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try:

```
int(span.text[pos+2:])
```